# Portability of programs written in non-portable languages i.e. C/C++

Tags: java, c, installation, portability

How is it possible that many popular programs, such as Microsoft Office, are written in languages such as C, C++ and assembly yet the same installer works on any computer with the appropriate OS? Is it because the installer actually compiles the source code on the computer? Is it because AMD and Intel share basically the same instruction set?

I have heard C is portable, but in what sense is Java more portable than C? What then is the point of a virtual machine?

Comment: Voting to close: this question is overly broad and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: 'Portable' isn't a binary state. It is a cost function. Any program is portable given enough time and money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is nothing inherantly nonportable about C or C++.  Portability concerns only arise when calling operating system or compiler-specific functions.  In the case of assembly language programming, the lack of portability is generally due to instruction set concerns.  If restricting the target machine set appropriately, those portability problems may or not matter.
2. The "appropriate OS" is a hint that portability (in the strictest sense) is not a concern, since a well-defined execution environment exists.  That is, the binary provided will only run on Intel ISA machines running Windows.
3. The installer almost certainly *does not* compile source code for the computer.
4. Yes, because of the shared instruction set (and operating system in this case), the program should run equally well on both.  If you tried to run that binary on a computer with a different archicture (ARM, for example), or under a different operating system (Linux, perhaps), you'd be out of luck.
5. Java provides a bunch of APIs and a virtual machine that can (sometimes) allow code to be compiled once and then deployed on multiple architectures and operating systems.  Because they abstract the interface to the system through Java API, you don't have to worry about porting all of that code when you want to deploy on a different system.  C provides only some standard libraries, but doesn't specify a particular machine architecture.
6. The point of the virtual machine is precisely this abstraction - instead of writing a program that compiles to code running natively in the instruction set of the host processor, you write one that compiles to code that runs in the virtual machine.  The implementer of the VM takes care of the necessary translation from VM instructions to native host instructions and the translation *back* of the results.

Comment: C and C++ (when used carefully) are portable across diverse computer architectures at the source code level; Java is portable across diverse computer architectures at the binary level, because it relies on this additional level of abstraction, the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). The JVM itself is written in C, and its source code can and has been compiled under many computer architectures. One way to think of this is a progression away from the "raw" hardware and towards more portability: machine language -> macro assembler -> C -> C++ -> Java.

Comment: @theglauber"C and C++...are portable across diverse computer architectures at the source code level; Java is portable across diverse computer architectures at the binary level" isn't this supporting the fact that C/C++ programs WOULD need to be recompiled by the installer?

Comment: @Celeritas, not if the installer is only intended to run on machines with the same architecture and operating system (which is normally the case).

Comment: +1 technically C is much more portable than Java.  It can be made to compile and run of just about any hardware which can run a program.  Java is much easier to port *provided* that hardware+OS has a JVM.

Comment: Standard C, certainly.  But the portability of a program really depends on what it does and how it does it more than the language it's written in.

Comment: In school I'm taught the difference between Java and C/C++ is Java's more portable and C/C++ is faster. Obviously this is a generalization but is it wrong? I was told, for example, in an interview if someone asks what's the difference between C and Java you'd say Java is portable and C is not. What's a better answer?

Comment: If you need a canned answer: "Normally, Java programs run on a virtual machine, and C programs are compiled to run directly on the target machine." But it's probably better to get a good understanding of what's really going on so that you can have an intelligent discussion about it with the interviewer.  Do people really ask questions like that?

Comment: I've never been asked this question at an interview, it is rather stupid and so is the profs canned answer.

Comment: "Java's more portable and C/C++ is faster" - perhaps so, in a very narrow sense; but in real-world applications, "faster" is determined more often by the algorithm and space/time trade-offs (e.g. effect of memory usage on program speed) than by the computer language used.

Comment: @Celeritas consider a C interpreter written in Java. Languages don't have speed; There are no requirements regarding speed in the C, C++ or Java standards. Have you ever heard of the "abstract machine"? It is a theoretical machine that is used in the C and C++ standards to describe the languages in terms of semantics. What does this say about the portability of those two languages?

Comment: @CarlNorum regarding point 4. Often times the same program works on different versions of the same OS for example the same program installs on Windows XP and Windows 7. Is this because the operating system calls are the same? But between Linux and Windows they probably wouldn't be.

Comment: Yes, OS vendors often try to maintain some amount of interface compatibility from version to version, which is why system calls are often similar between releases.  If they changed (for example, if a system call your program used was removed), then you'd be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you read any book on the history of C and how and why it was designed you will see that C is designed to allow the same program to run on different operating systems and hardware

Answer (score 0):

In principle, C is a very portable language. There are really only two sources of portability problems:

1. Invalid programs whose behavior is undefined or deep into the realm of "implementation-defined" in ways that actually vary between implementations, but which *happen to work* with whatever OS/compiler/phase-of-the-moon combination they were written for.
2. The fact that C has a *very light* standard library such that almost any useful program depends on further interfaces (not defined in the language standard) for communicating with the user, OS, and outside world.

As an aside: As far as the second point is concerned, we were on the verge of getting past that with **every** relevant real-world system except Windows adopting POSIX (a standard that basically expands on C and gives you most of the stuff that's missing in point #2 above). But then along came Android and iOS to fragment things again...